# Modify node process environment or arguments runtime

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to modify `process`?

For example `process.argv.push('something')`?

It seems like other modules do not pick up the changes in the arguments.

I want to "trick" another module into acting like some argument was specified when the process was started.

Is process instantiated for each module on load and therefore globally immutable?

Comment: I did try yes, and it does not seem to be a shared instance across modules.

Comment: Perhaps you should expand your question, it's unclear what it is you want to accomplish.

Comment: I want to "trick" another module into acting like some argument was specified when the process was started.

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't be possible, provided that you make sure that you change `process.argv` before that module is loaded (or rather, before that module uses `process.argv`).

Comment: Ah. Obviously. It seems like the dependency is a singleton and instantiated at an earlier stage also. I was afraid maybe process was instantiated for each module on load, and that it was not possible to modify it globally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **can** modify `process`, just make sure that you do it before anything that is dependant on it loads and parses it.

Comment: You my friend are a savior. For my future self: Remember: process is modifiable and modify it before your other program reads it