# Node CLI app with console color on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a command line app, and when I run the app via `myApp --arg1=true` the console does not output in color.

If I pass `--color` as an argument like this `myApp --arg1=true --color`, then the output displays in color.

Is there a way for me to do this without passing the parameter? I have tried adding `process.env.color` above the [colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) package, but that just displays the output as normal.

```
process.env.color = ''
require('colors')
```

I have tried setting the value of `color` as well to: 'true', 'always', 'yes'

### Edit

Color does display on Linux, but not on Windows

Comment: commandline arguments are stored in [process.argv array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361287/modify-node-process-environment-or-arguments-runtime), try `process.argv.push("--color")`

Comment: That fixes the issue!