# How to mock or stub process.argv

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, ava

How do I mock or stub `process.argv` so that it can return a specific argument?

I tried using [Sinon.js](https://sinonjs.org/) like this:

```js
beforeEach(
  () => {
    sandbox.stub(
      process.argv.slice(2)[0], 'C:\\home\\project\\assignment'
    ).value('--local');
  }
);

afterEach(
  () => {
    sandbox.restore();
  }
);

test(
  'it replace value of node argument',
  () => {
    assert(process.argv.slice(2)[0], '--local');
  }
);
```

But I keep getting an error that says trying to stub property `'C:\\home\\project\\assignment'` of `undefined`.

Answer (score 6):

Since 29.x, Jest has a [replaceProperty](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestreplacepropertyobject-propertykey-value) method.

```
jest.replaceProperty(process, 'argv', ['what', 'ever', 'you', 'like']);
```

The advantage is this mock can be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

You can rebind `process.argv` (cf. [Modify node process environment or arguments runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361287/modify-node-process-environment-or-arguments-runtime)):

```js
import assert from 'node:assert/strict';
import test from 'node:test';

test.describe(
  () => {
    const originalArgv = process.argv;

    test.afterEach(
      () => {
        process.argv = originalArgv;
      }
    );

    test.test(
      () => {
        process.argv = process.argv.slice(0, 1).concat(['--local']);
        assert.equal(process.argv[1], '--local');
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to *modify* `process.argv` in the tests instead of *rebinding* it like in @LinDu’s answer, you can save and restore `process.argv` by making each test work on its *own** shallow copy of the original `process.argv`, so that the tests don’t affect one another:

```js
import assert from 'node:assert/strict';
import test from 'node:test';

test.describe(
  () => {
    const originalArgv = process.argv;

    test.beforeEach(
      () => {
        process.argv = [...originalArgv];  // own shallow copy
      }
    );

    test.test(
      () => {
        process.argv[1] = '--local';
        assert.equal(process.argv[1], '--local');
      }
    );
  }
);
```

---

* Note that making each test work on a *shared* shallow copy of the original `process.argv` won’t work since the tests will affect one another:

```js
// THIS CODE IS INCORRECT!

import assert from 'node:assert/strict';
import test from 'node:test';

test.describe(
  () => {
    const originalArgv = [...process.argv];  // shared shallow copy

    test.beforeEach(
      () => {
        process.argv = originalArgv;
      }
    );

    test.test(
      () => {
        process.argv[1] = '--local';
        assert.equal(process.argv[1], '--local');
      }
    );
  }
);
```